# Output word with part requested

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class CarCareChoice2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    final int NUM_OF_ITEMS = 8;
    String[] validChoices = {"oil change", "tire rotation", "battery check", "brake inspection"};
    int[] prices = {25, 22, 15, 5};
    String strOptions;
    String careChoice;
    double choicePrice = 0.0;
    boolean validChoice = false;
    strOptions = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter one of the following care options: oil change, tire rotation, battery check, or brake inspection");
    careChoice = strOptions;
    for(int x = 0; x < NUM_OF_ITEMS; ++x)
    {
        if(careChoice.equals(validChoices[x]))
        {
            validChoice = true;
            choicePrice = prices[x];
        }
     }
     if(validChoice)
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The price of a(an) " + careChoice + " is $" + choicePrice);
     else
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry - invalid entry");

    }
}
```

User should only have to input the first 3 letters of the service and get the service they entered and its matching price. Here is my code so far.

Comment: what is your problem

Comment: User should only have to input the first 3 letters of the service and get the service they entered and its matching price.

Comment: you are failing to explain your issue

Comment: When the user inputs atleast the first three letters of a choice such as bat, oil, bra it should automatically select that choice and display the price without the user needing to type the whole thing out.

Comment: So, you mean that user should input `oil` or `bra` or `bat` or `tir` and get the desired service? This doesn't looks user friendly (imho), why not use a `JComboBox` or a `JRadioButton` with a `ButtonGroup` instead?

Comment: It's just so the user doesn't need to type out the choices fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> User should only have to input the first 3 letters of the service and get the service they entered and its matching price

This doesn't looks like an approach I would use, it's not user friendly (IMHO), there are other ways to solve it (ordered in how I think would solve it the best)

1. Using a `showInputDialog` with predefined options, which will look like a `JComboBox`

   [image]
2. Using a custom `JPanel` which will be passed as the message and use `JRadioButton`s so user can select one of them (of course you can change the [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to look different

   [image]
3. And lastly the ugly way, asking user to write it and comparing using [`.toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) on both the `services` variable and `userInput` variable, using [`.startsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) method (which is what you're trying to accomplish):

   [image]

Where all of them produce a similar output to this one:

[image]

Comment / Uncomment each of the methods to see how they behave, and choose accordingly, the code that produces each of the above outputs is:

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CarCareChoice {
    
    private JFrame frame;
    private String[] services = {"Oil change", "Tire rotation", "Battery check", "Brake inspection"};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CarCareChoice carCareChoice = new CarCareChoice();
//              carCareChoice.comboWay();
//              carCareChoice.radioWay();
                carCareChoice.textUglyWay();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void comboWay() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        
        String userSelection = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please select one of the following", "Service selection", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, services, services[0]);
        
        if (userSelection != null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The service selected was: " + userSelection);
        }
    }
    
    public void radioWay() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        JRadioButton[] buttons = new JRadioButton[services.length];
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JRadioButton(services[i]);
            group.add(buttons[i]);
            pane.add(buttons[i]);
        }
        
        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, pane, "Service selection", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        
        JRadioButton userSelection = null;
        
        if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            for (Component c : pane.getComponents()) {
                if (c instanceof JRadioButton) {
                    if (((JRadioButton) c).isSelected()) {
                        userSelection = (JRadioButton) c;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (userSelection != null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Service selected: " + userSelection.getText());
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "C'mon man! Select something");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void textUglyWay() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        
        String userSelection = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please select one of the following", "Service selection", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        
        if (userSelection != null && !userSelection.equals("")) {
            for (String s : services) {
                if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith(userSelection.toLowerCase())) {
                    userSelection = s;
                    break;
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The service selected was: " + userSelection);
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Important Note:

Your program was also not placed on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) which could cause some threading issues in the future, so be sure to place all your programs in it as I did with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Your constructor here
        }
    });
}
```